# PHP / HTML remember selected value after submit - options populated from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have the following code which basically is a drop down menu. When the user selects an option and submits the selection, the value is echoed. The option values are obtained from a MySQL table.

This is my code.

```
<form name="hello" id="hello" method="post" action="chooser.php">
    <select name="primaryCatResult" id="primaryCatResult" >
        <?php
        while ($result = $sqlUpdatePrimary->fetch()) {
            $primary_category = $result['primary_category'];
            ?>
            <option  
            value = "<?php echo $primary_category; ?>"> 

            <?php echo $_POST['primary_category'] == $result['primary_category'] ?'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
            <?php echo $primary_category; ?></option>";
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php

//Record and display selection
if(isset($_POST['primaryCatResult'])){
    echo $_POST['primaryCatResult'];
}
else {
    echo 'Choose a primary category';
}
```

The above form works as desired except that I want that after the option is selected and the form is submitted, I'd like the selection from the drop down menu would remain selected.

I'm not conviced about this line of code:

```
<?php echo $_POST['primary_category'] == $result['primary_category'] ?'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
```

No errors are displayed in the error log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<option>` closes before you can output whether it's selected. Move the selected before the closing `>` in your opening `<option>` tag. You also need to use the field's name (`primaryCatResult`) in place of the column name `primary_category`.

Should look like this:

```
<option value = "<?php echo $primary_category; ?>"
<?php echo $_POST['primaryCatResult'] == $result['primary_category'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>
> 
<?php echo $primary_category; ?></option>";
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you first of all. I tried your solution the problem still remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option value="<?php echo $primary_category; ?>" 
<?php echo $_POST['primary_category'] == $result['primary_category'] ? 'selected' : '' ?>>
<?php echo $primary_category; ?></option>";
```

You were closing the option after value. Not sure if your logic itself is working though.

Also you can just do `selected` rather than `selected="selected"`

Comment: The problem is still remaining the same. The select is being reset.

Answer (score 0):

The concept should work, except the code has extra bracket that extract the 'selected' statement.

```
   <?php
    while ($result = $sqlUpdatePrimary->fetch()) {
        $primary_category = $result['primary_category'];
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $primary_category; ?>"

        <?php echo ($_POST['primary_category'] == $result['primary_category'] ? " selected='selected'>" : ">") ?>  // close bracket.
        <?php echo $primary_category; ?></option>";
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```